# Strange popup in Android Studio

Tags: windows, android-studio

Each click I perform in Android Studio (every tab in the settings bar, every button like "build", etc) shows some strange hint popup.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

How to prevent it from showing up?

I am running on windows 10.
Android Studio version:
Android Studio 2.2.2
Build #AI-145.3360264, built on October 18, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

It was key promoter plugin which created these popups.